# How do I delay a for loop in swift without interrupting the main thread?

Tags: swift, iphone, flashlight

I am trying to read through a string one character a time delaying .1 seconds before moving on to the next character.

I have tried implementing the delay function inside the for loop but it has two problems. 
1. The delay is inconsistent and does not take the same amount of time when moving between characters. 
2. It disrupts the main thread which I think is the cause of the camera view freezing. However, I think it is also possible that activating the flashlight while the camera is on freezes the signal, causing the glitch.

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
        deadline: DispatchTime.now () + Double(Int64(delay * 
    Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: 
    closure)
}

func scriptReader(){
    let str = "10101000001111110000110"
    for i in 0..<str.count {

        delay(Double(i) * 0.5) { 
            let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy:  i) 
            self.flash(number: str[index]) 
        }
    }
}
func flash(number: Character){
    guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: 
 AVMediaType.video) else { return }
    guard device.hasTorch else { return }

    if number == "0" {
        print("off")
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()

            if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureDevice.TorchMode.on) {
                device.torchMode = AVCaptureDevice.TorchMode.off
            }
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    if number == "1"{
        print("on")
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()

            if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureDevice.TorchMode.off) {
                do {
                    try device.setTorchModeOn(level: 1.0)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re your first concern, the use of a series of `asyncAfter` are going to suffer from “timer coalescing”, where the OS will group future, individually scheduled timers to fire all at once, to make best use of the device battery (the less often the OS needs to wake up the device, the better the battery life). The further out the scheduled timers are, the more coalescing the OS will do.

One can avoid this by using a repeating `Timer`:

```
func handle(string: String) {
    guard !string.isEmpty else { return }

    var index = string.startIndex
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { timer in
        if string[index] == "0" {
            // handle "0"
        } else {
            // handle not "0"
        }

        index = string.index(after: index)
        if index == string.endIndex  { timer.invalidate() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed the issue of the time interval. I am still having an issue where when the flashlight turns on the camera feed ceases to work. Do you know if it is possible to operate the flashlight while having a camera feed active? Interestingly, the flashlight does not stop the camera on my friend's phone (iPhone 7) but it does not work on mine (iPhone X.) Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @I.Winson - “Do you know if it is possible to operate the flashlight while having a camera feed active?” ... Are you doing any `lockForConfiguration` elsewhere in your code? What values are returned by `isInUseByAnotherApplication` and `isSuspended`?

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as this may also work:

```
let threadName = "FlashThread"
let string = "10101000001111110000110"

//Create a custom thread
DispatchQueue(label: threadName).async {
    print("Thread Start")

    //Start loop
    string.forEach { (c) in
        print(c)

        //Do something on main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.flash(number: c)
        }

        //Put your thread to sleep for a second
        sleep(1)
    }

    print("Thread END")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue now. The first problem was solved with the timer code provided by Rob. This stopped the freezing of the main thread and now the code iterates through the String with consistent timing between. 
The second problem was fixed by eliminating multiple instances of `AVCaptureDevice`, once that was fixed the code worked. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -2):

I think camera freezes because you call its property every time in for loop, do it once, pass its property to obtain in your func

try this code to fix your glitch

```
    func scriptReader(){
    let str = "10101000001111110000110"
    guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
    guard device.hasTorch else { return }
    for i in 0..<str.count {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i) * 0.5) {
            let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy:  i)
            self.flash(number: str[index])
        }
    }
}

func flash(device: AVCaptureDevice, isOn: Bool) {
    do {
        try device.lockForConfiguration()
        device.torchMode = isOn ? AVCaptureDevice.TorchMode.off : device.setTorchModeOn(level: 1.0)
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i adapted your solution with a couple of modifications but am still having the glitch issue. The flash method had some logic that I needed so I kept that and I am not completely sure what the importance of the isOn variable is. Does anyone know if it is possible to control the flashlight without causing the glitch? The freeze only occurs when the flashlight is ON.

Comment: `func scriptReader(){
        let str = "10101000001111110000110"
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        guard device.hasTorch else { return }
        for i in 0..<str.count {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i) * 0.5) {
                let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy:  i)
                self.flash(device: device, number: str[index])
            }
        }
    }`